# Copy tables between access databases

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access

I have two access databases and would like to find a way to copy tables from one
database to the other. The copied table has to keep the same strucure and data.

I already tried to fiddle around with [sqlBulkcopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) but all information i can found about it
is using sqlBulkCopy to tranfer tables to sql server.

Can I use sqlBulkCopy to copy tables between mdb files or is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
insert into [AccessTable] 
    select * from [MS Access;DATABASE=D:\My Documents\db2.mdb].[AccessTable2]
```

Comment: Got it working, thanks. Only one problem, this does not copy the keys and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the whole table including keys and data from one Access database into the other by running this in the destination database:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", "C:\Source_Database.mdb", acTable, "Source_Table", "Destination_Table"
```